# Python - Get 'i' variable assigned in if block

Tags: python, if-statement

Hello I am trying to check some chars in a string. I found this code in the web. It works but I need to get `i` variable inside of the if block.

This is my code:

```
chars = set('qwertyuopasdfghjklizxcvbnm!"^+%&/()=?')

if any((i in chars) for i in myString):
   myIndex = myString.index(i)
```

But I've got this:

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

walrus operator to the rescue !

```py
if any(((i := x) in chars) for x in myString):
   myIndex = myString.index(i)
```

this assigns x to i outside the comprehension so it's visible inside the block.